# Perl memory leak in threads (threads don't release memory)

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory-leaks

I am now searching for 2 weeks about this problem and seems that I can't find any answer just searching on the web.

So, here is two piece of code:

1:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

#
# RELEASE MEMORY
#

use threads;

my @child;

$ii=0;


while (1)
{
  my @child = threads->new(\&test, "test");
  $_->detach for @child;
  print "$ii\n";
  $ii++;
}

sub test {
    my ($ee) = 0;    
}
```

2:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

#
# DO NOT RELEASE MEMORY
#

use threads;

my @child;

$ii=0;


for($ii=0;$ii<2000;$ii++) {
    my @child = threads->new(\&test, "test");
    $_->detach for @child;
    print "$ii\n";
}

while(1)
{
  sleep(10);
}

sub test {
    my ($ee) = 0;    
}
```

So here's the problem. The first code run only one infinite loop and it release memory back to operating system about each 2 seconds (according to ps)

The second code is releasing memory too but only when he's running inside the "for" loop.
Once it exit the for loop and enter the infinite loop all the memory that have not been freed into the for loop is never released back to the operating system.

Is anybody experiencing the same issue ?

Perl: (v5.16.1) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

OS: Debian 6.0.5

Thanks a lot

---

Edit 1:
I used 800 threads and all verified that they exit by printing the $ee var.

But once entering the while(1) loop here's the ps aux | grep perl output:

```
root@srv:~# ps aux | grep perl
root      6807 41.5  2.5 387780 209580 pts/0   S+   16:38   0:02 /opt/ActivePerl-5.16/bin/perl /home/tttlast.pl
root      7627  0.0  0.0   7548   856 pts/1    S+   16:38   0:00 grep perl
```

So all thread exited but the memory usage is still 2.5% of my server total memory.
So unless I kill the program the memory is still in use.

---

Edit 2:

I resolved my problem, I changed my structure. In fact the main program (the long running one) have been separated and I use small program who wait before all threads finish to exit.

This way It doesn't full the virtual memory and other daemon are not killed.

Thanks to everyone leading me to that solution.

Comment: I've tried them on OS X 10.8 / Perl 5.16.0.  The behavior I see for the first is memory usage levels off after a few thousand threads at about 6 megs resident.  The second levels off at about the same level and remains there at the sleep.  The thread memory is obviously being released in both cases.  Could you post more evidence that memory isn't being released?  Maybe the `ps` output every second?

Comment: Added the ps output. In fact the real program is more complex, just didn't posted here to not being flamed, but It run for long time and each hours open about 250 to 900 threads which full the memory to about 10% of my total memory and never release. But this is the exact same way into the second example. Let me know if you need more informations. thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't Perl *only* free memory when a *process* exits? This has been a long-standing "feature", and I couldn't find any evidence of optimizations regarding threading in the  recent perldeltas. I am more suprised by the *decrease* of memory usage you claim to have witnessed than the "leak".

Comment: [If Perl is using the system's malloc, Perl *may* release memory back to the operating system](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-free-an-array-or-hash-so-my-program-shrinks-).  Check `perl -wle 'use Config;  print $Config{usemymalloc}'`. Also, [ps is not a wholly reliable way of checking memory usage on Linux](http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html), you might try pmap. Finally, I don't know how `ps` deals with threads.

Comment: Just checked the first and the second script with pmap and same results (first free memory and second don't free memory). In this example I could just check if threads are running and when no one is running I kill and restart the application but with my real program I cannot do this. I also checked perl -wle 'use Config; print $Config{usemymalloc}' and It state "n" probably for no. So if I haven't compiled perl to use malloc why it is releasing memory from script one but not from script two ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "issue" here. This is all normal, expected behavior. If this is causing you some kind of problem, you haven't explained what it is.

There's no reason to return virtual memory to the operating system because virtual memory isn't a scarce resource. There's no reason to return physical memory to the operating system because the operating system will take it if it has a better use for it anyway.

There's no evidence it's a memory leak. Test results suggest that there is no case where the memory usage increases without bound -- in all cases it levels off eventually.

Comment: Just verified and you are right. The memory used by other processes is taken when the perl program need memory. The issue in fact is that other process from perl take memory are killed, like mysql and mail server. And that the perl program use mysql and the mail server to run. Should I edit my post or post another question ? Btw thanks a lot

Comment: You just shouldn't create so many threads. It's not sensible.